# What statistic test to use?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, t-test, spss

I am new to statistics!

I have 2 groups of city population based on education level (group A: educated, group B: without education)

I try to figure out if there is a difference between the number of people who live in the city, based on education

What statistic tests to use to prove the following hypothesis, or what steps to follow?

I already calculated mean and standard deviation for both groups, and I also know N for both, but I am stuck from here, what test to use.

H0: no difference between education level

Ha: more "educated" people than "without education" in the city

Ha2: more "without education" people than "educated" people in the city

Also, is it possible to have 2 alternative hypothesis, or I should think to state the Ha as a single hypothesis? How can I make it into 1 alternative hypothesis?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You have a sample from your population of interest, and your result is count data? That is you have a count of how many people in your sample are educated/non-educated and live in a given city? Are there multiple cities? Can you show us a sample of your data?

Comment: Yes, I upload the data. A brief explanaition is that for each ID (1,2,3, etc), it represents a 1sq km cell, on which interview of people were taken. The number under "EDUCATED" represents the number of respondents who claimed have education, in that particular 1sq km cell, same for "non educated".

Comment: Are these cells all from the same city? Are these cells of interest to you or do you want to compare only based on all the cells?

Comment: Cell 26 has relatively a lot educated people, cell 6 has relatively a lot uneducated people. This shows that there might be a strong non-homogeneous distribution of the education levels. This means that you need to be careful in creating an aggregated statistic. How did you perform the sampling? This is gonna have an influence on the result. For instance a consideration is a question like: Does cell 26 have more respondents because the population density is larger, or because you sampled more effectively?

Comment: @user2974951 : yes, same city  ; @ Sextus Empiricus : the sample is given to me for  my homework, ; no text given about population density, but I assume that is the reason. The main task is to either prove one of the hypothesis, but my biggest problem is that they ask me to either prove: more educated in city or more uneducated in city. If it was with only one null and alternative hypothesis, I would have done an independent t test

Comment: @gis1234 This type of data is a tricky and maybe that is not what was the intention of the homework. What is your homework supposed to teach you, just to do a t-test? Or are you supposed to be critical about your data as well? Without knowledge of the sampling process you can not create a statistical model and you can not perform a statistical test that makes sense. [All models are wrong](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_models_are_wrong), yet some are still useful, but a random model not inspired by any background knowledge is nonsense.

Comment: *"I try to figure out if there is a difference between the number of people who live in the city, based on education"* Could you state this task more clearly? What is the literal question you got? Are you testing whether the numbers of people with and without education are different (e.g. do a t-test or estimate a binomial proportion), or are you testing whether the distribution of education is not uniform (do a chi-squared test for the contingency table)?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Yes, I try to see if the number of people in the city, differs based on education. I ll paste the exact text in the next comment. Maybe I suck at statistics and I can't explain the problem clearly.

Comment: Your first task is to, with the help of the available data, evaluate if there is a significant difference between the 
number of people living in Lund that have higher education and the people that do not. So 
you should ask yourself, are there significantly more people with a university degree, or 
more people without a degree, or are the proportions approximately equal? Of course, 
you want to prove your results “statistically”, and will therefore use a hypothesis test (or 
tests) to help you solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the part about the two hypotheses:

Normally you just report the effect that you measured. For instance:

- An estimate for the number of educated people in the city is 60%, this is more than half the population.

The statistical test, e.g. a t-test, is performed in order to find out whether the null hypothesis is correct or not and to characterise the significance of the estimated effect size. The test is used to give an indication of the probability of a false positive result. If the p-value is high, then this means that the measured effect (e.g. that 60%) is not a strong evidence against the null hypothesis (since a deviation of this size could likely happen even when the null hypothesis is true of the p-value is high).

---

The idea about a one-sided t-test is to adjust the power of the test and this is useful when you are more interested in effects of a particular direction. (btw I write t-test but you might consider a different test, e.g. a test for a [binomial proportion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial))

Comment: Please see 
https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6304/my-upvoting-policy, 
when you find a question sufficiently clear to 
write an answer, consider to upvote the question!

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the [t-test](https://uc-r.github.io/t_test) comes into play for this (check its assumptions). Also, have a look at a [general](https://www.texasoft.com/tutorial-statistics-compare-2-groups.htm) procedure.

Comment: Please see 
https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6304/my-upvoting-policy, 
when you find a question sufficiently clear to 
write an answer, consider to upvote the question!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of statistics !

As a beginner myself, I always found references on "how to select the good statistical test" useful.
This [paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2996580/) by might be a good place to start understanding your data and how to properly analyze the results. You can follow the step by step tree to select the most appropriate method.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Please see 
https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6304/my-upvoting-policy, 
when you find a question sufficiently clear to 
write an answer, consider to upvote the question!